# Physical interpretation of a multi-time (more than 2) autocorrelation function: non-Gaussian diffusion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In non-equilibrium statistical mechanics, the time-autocorrelation functions become the cornerstone of various theories and models. One such important autocorrelation is the velocity autocorrelation function, given by,
$$
C_v(t) = \int_0^{t}dt_1\int_0^{t_1}dt_2 \left< v(t_1) v(t_2) \right>
$$
which can be physically interpretted as a measure of how velocity of a particle at some time $t_1$ is correlated to velocity at another time $t_2$. So for example, if particle had a velocity in $+x$ direction at $t_1$, and it became $-x$ at $t_2$, then the autocorrelation will be negative at $(t_2 - t_1)$.

But when we define higher-order velocity autocorrelations, it is difficult wrap my head around their physical interpretation. For example, the next non-zero velocity autocorrelation is 4-time correlation function given by,
$$
H_v(t) = \int_0^{t}dt_1\int_0^{t_1}dt_2\int_0^{t_2}dt_3\int_0^{t_3}dt_4 \left< v(t_1) v(t_2)v(t_3) v(t_4) \right>
$$

In this case, it seems, it describes the non-Gaussian behaviour in the Brownian motion of the particle, but it is difficult to comprehend physically, why it is so.